# Converting a string that contains multiple words to a vector of words

Tags: java, string, vector, io

I have an InputStream file, I have to put all the words from that file into a vector of strings.
I tried multiple things to convert the InputStream file to where I can read all the words in it, but no matter what I always end up with a long string with all the words.
How can I separate all the words in the file to that I can put them in a vector of strings?
here is my code for the conversion from InputStream file to string:

```
public static InputStream vocabDoc = Librarian.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Vocabulary.txt");

String str = new Scanner(vocabDoc,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
System.out.println(str);
```

this is what the file "vocabDoc" contains (exactly):

```
file
vocabulary
test
is
one
this
for
```

if I try to put it in a vector it always come back as:

```
[file

vocabulary

test

is

one

this

for

]
```

and if I take out the `"\n"` it comes out as: `[filevocabularytestisonethisfor]`, my goal is to have something like: `[file, vocabulary, test, is, one, this, for]` instead.

I'm not sure where to go from here and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the expected output, simply do it without using any explicit delimiter. Using [`Scanner#hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()), you can test if the file more words to read.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream vocabDoc = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Vocabulary.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(vocabDoc);
        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            vector.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(vector);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[file, vocabulary, test, is, one, this, for]
```

Comment: this gives me an error because File(InputStream) does not work. I need to use the InputStream to get the outside file, I cannot just write it in.

Comment: @Student - What is the type of `vocabDoc`? I suggest you edit your question to add more code so that it becomes clear.

Comment: Ok, I added the file description.

Comment: @Student - I've updated the answer accordingly. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: seems to be working just fine. Thank you so much for the help!!! :)